# Bulgarian Visa Duration of Stay

Tags: visas, bulgaria

I have a short stay Bulgarian visa (Type C) that is valid from July 27th, 2015 to August 17th, 2015. The duration of stay on the visa is 6 days. Will it be legal to arrive on July 27th, 2015 and depart on August 2nd, 2015 i.e. does it count as a stay of six days or seven?

Comment: That's 7 days, you would be 1 day out of time.

Answer (score 2):

As @GayotFow already commented, that's seven days, not six. Both the day you enter and the day you leave do count in the total. Enforcement is primarily based on the date/stamps, not on a minute-by-minute count of the time spent.

If you find it difficult to compute the duration, you can use the [calculator](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/border-crossing/schengen_calculator_en.html) mentioned in [How does the Schengen 90/180 rule work?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/about-schengen-90-180-rule). While, as of June 2015, Bulgaria still hasn't joined the Schengen area and cannot issue Schengen visas, it does apply the exact same rules.

Comment: I do certainly believe that this counts as a total of seven days. Here's the full story. I got my visa for the following itinerary. Arrival: 27-07-15, Departure: 02-08-15. And the visa issued to me allows me to stay for six days. I have talked to the embassy about this issue. And they have maintained that this constitutes a six days stay, claiming that Bulgaria follows certain Schengen policies, while not others. I'll be mostly likely flying to Sofia from San Francisco, and I am not sure if the immigration officials in America know which rules Bulgaria likes to follow, which they don't.

Comment: @swaqar It's all very odd but unfortunately I don't have any practical experience with that. What I can tell you is that won't see any immigration officials in the US but will have to convince the airline you have the right visa to enter Bulgaria. If you could get the embassy's point of view in writing (even in an email conversation) and bring that with you it could help with the airline or with the border guards in Bulgaria.